# Returning name of the concrete implementation of a func<> delegate

Tags: c#, reflection, nameof

tl;dr version: `nameof(ToCelsius)` returns `ToCelsius`. I want something that returns the name of the underlying function, `ToCelsiusByA`, though.

My `ToCelsius` is assigned a concrete implementation thus:

```
 Func<decimal,decimal> ToCelsius = ToCelsiusByA;
```

I then call the `ToCelsius` function:

```
var degreesC = ToCelsius(degreesF);
```

I'd like to name of the implemented function (`ToCelsiusByA`) returned, so I'm trying this:

```
Console.WriteLine(degreesF + " degrees F is " + degreesC + " degrees C! using " + nameof(ToCelsius));
```

but, of course, this shows 'ToCelsuis' in the string.

Comment: I think that you ask is only possible with reflection.

Comment: @Nekeniehl check out the answer below.

Comment: Always is a good time to learn =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(theDelegate.Method.Name);
```

but note: this won't work well for a range of scenarios involving delegates such as combined delegates or lambdas / anonymous methods.